# Error with swift installation in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I created a new project in ubuntu, with only the `main.swift`, with a simple `print(hello world)` and display this error.

```
guillermo@guillermo-Latitude-E6440:~/Descargas/Hola3$ swift build
Linking Executable:  .build/debug/Hola3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): ["/home/guillermo/Descargas/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin/swift-build-tool", "-f", "/home/guillermo/Descargas/Hola3/.build/debug/Hola3.o/llbuild.yaml"]
```

Comment: Do you have Glibc installed?

Comment: Can you verify from here https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/12/getting-started-with-swift-on-linux.html

Comment: ok , as I install glibc?

Comment: sonu kumar, i try that method and I were errors unfulfilled dependencies

Comment: May sound obvious, but try with a more recent version of Swift. You have 2016-01-25, at the time of my comment it's [2016-02-25](https://swift.org/builds/development/ubuntu1404/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-25-a/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-25-a-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz).

Comment: ok, now i have this error,                                                                       Compiling Swift Module 'Hola3' (1 sources)
Linking Hola3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures

Comment: Eric D, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You need the libgcc-*-dev package that provides crtbegin.o and a few other important libraries and object files vital to building programs on Ubuntu.  For example, on Ubuntu 14.04 it would be libgcc-4.8-dev.  The package should be installed if you install the gcc package:

```
apt-get install gcc
```